# Modify Maven settings.xml with SettingsWriter and keep comments

Tags: java, maven, settings

I need to add a new profile to the users settings.xml as part of an IDE Plugin. Currently I'm directly parsing and modifying the actual file, but I would prefer to use Maven APIs like [SettingsWriter](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-settings-builder/apidocs/org/apache/maven/settings/io/SettingsWriter.html).

Reading, modifying and writing works fine, but unfortunately comments and formatting are lost in this process. Is there a way to keep the comments, or a different API that I can use for this?

Comment: I checked the source code and org.apache.maven.settings.Settings does not contain comments, so it's definitely impossible with SettingsWriter API.

Comment: I solved this using Java standard XML APIs instead.